# How to set height based on the number of items in grid kendo ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

i have this kendo grid, i want to set the height to be auto adjusted based on the items.

if i select 5 items, i want to remove the empty space/padding appear below the rows.

here is the code.

```
function resizeGrid() {
    var gridElement = $("#grid");
    var dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content");
    var newHeight = gridElement.parent().innerHeight() - 2;
    var diff = gridElement.innerHeight() - dataArea.innerHeight();
    gridElement.height(newHeight);
    dataArea.height(newHeight - diff);
}
```

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4eNu4/1427/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your resizeGrid :

```
function resizeGrid() {
    $('.k-grid-content').css('height',$('.k-grid-content table').innerHeight()+'px');
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eNu4/1428/)

Comment: then the scrollbar is not visible

Comment: change this code $('.k-grid-content').css('height',$('#grid').innerHeight()+'px'); [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eNu4/1429/)